# Individual Items Owned by "One another"

Tags: possessives, quantifiers

The sentence is:

> I don’t mind being restricted from making changes, but we cannot efficiently troubleshoot if we’re relying on one another’s schedule**s**.

Is the 's' in "schedules" correct? It almost sounds, to me, that each individual has multiple schedules.

How should I word this if:

- Each person has a single schedule
- Each person has multiple schedules
- We all share a single schedule
- We all share multiple schedules

Comment: Please limit your post to a single question. Multiple questions require multiple posts. If you pick one way you would like it said, that can be answered.

Comment: I feel like the question is the distinction between unique and shared possession. The verbosity makes it look like multiple questions, but it's a singular concept.

Comment: Your first part of the post is the distinction, but you specifically ask for 4 answers with your bullet points. If you remove the bullet points and simply ask, "What does this sentence convey with it's current usage of **schedules**?", it would be answerable. As it stands, you have multiple questions and require multiple answers. It is more difficult to answer a multi-part question effectively.

Comment: @Hank I'm with Goodies -- it's a general question about how we express the relationship between the number of possessors and the number of possessions. He simply enumerated all the cases that need to be covered in his bullet list.

Comment: @Barmar My problem with it is that the enumeration will require 4 answers, bringing down the odds that someone will answer all 4 versions perfectly, along with it possibly being opinion-based. That is the reason multi-part questions are frowned-upon, regardless of how related they are.

Answer (score 1):

First, if there's just a single schedule shared by everyone, we don't use the plural *schedules*.

Second, if the schedule or schedules are shared by everyone, it's unusual to use the phrase *one anoother's*. That's usually used to indicate that things are being exchanged or distinguished between members of the group. For common ownership, we usually use *our*.

The tricky case is distinguishing between each person having a single (non-shared) schedule and each person having multiple schedules. In both cases, there is more than one schedule involved, so we use the plural word. If you need to resolve the ambiguity, you'll need to express it differently.

So we have:

- Each person has a single schedule **each other's schedules**
- Each person has multiple schedules **each other's schedules**
- We all share a single schedule **our schedule**
- We all share multiple schedules **our schedules**

There's still ambiguity in the last case, though. It just indicates that there are multiple people and multiple schedules, but doesn't actually say how they relate to each other.